# 'Open with explorer' via http makes Explorer crash

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, open-with-explorer

We currently have the effect that when clicking **Open with explorer** in a document library **we can't add / edit / change items**. The folder opens but as soon as we try to add something the **explorer.exe freezes.** Same goes for mapping a library to a drive letter.

By default we access our intranet via **http**. About a year ago we added the option to access it via https.
And when accessing our Intranet via **https** everything works fine.

Anyone else has this feature/bug? Is there a way to fix it (a patch that might have been responsible)?

We use SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2. Client OS is Windows 10.

**Edit1**: Here are our AAM / IIS settings:
[image]
[image]

**Edit2**: We just got hold of a laptop without the latest patches and the behavior is the same. So our Patchday wasn't the issue here.

**Edit3**: We tried rewriting the URLs through our KEMP load balancer but the result is a 'broken' intranet due to the hard links.

**Edit4**: taking a look with fiddler revealed that as soon as I try to create a new folder this happens (the blurred URL is always 'intranet.company.com):
[image]

The only 302 message I can think of is the error page we set in IIS. But this has been made ~2 months before we encountered this issue.
[image]

**Edit5**: Trying to upload a file (credits.txt) takes some time and then presents me with these messages including a 504:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set up AAM for you intranet sites? If you set up AAM, then you need to access via https.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that does not fix this issue. Removing the https AAM entry (and its IIS binding) does not solve this issue. I updated the question with our AAM/IIS config. Also with these settings everything has been running fine for a year.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you still have the option to access the application through HTTP?

Comment: We still have lots of links within our Intranet (3000+ Site Collections) pointing directly to http ://intranet.company.com/*. Changing those manually would be 'challenging'. I also looked for PowerShell to help us here but couldn't come up with something (then again i am not super familiar with PS).

Comment: You could use URL rewrite to change all http:// requests to https://. Check this [link](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fiddler screenshot (edit3) indicates that the request #76 returns with a 302
i.e. it is redirected to the root and then results in a 401 (not authorised)

Can you try to grant the user read access to the root site on your farm? and then re-test?

Can you also try to disable the custom error page? (and restart IIS) would be good if we can exclude this as a cause.

Paul

Comment: Resetting the custom error page in IIS and the web.config did the trick. However I don't fully understand how it took so long for this behavior to show up(we set it almost 2 months ago) and why it threw a 404 message. Also all users have access to root site and  that 404 page. THANK YOU for pointing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I would fire up Fiddler and intercept the network traffic between the client and SharePoint. Can you establish a direct connection to one of the front-end servers by changing your local hosts file? This way you bypass the load balancer.
Paul

Comment: Thank you. The load balancer is currently not being used. However Fiddler revealed that when trying to create a folder it answers with many 401 / 302 messages. I updated my initial question.

Comment: Cool. Great news.